# Publishing Free/Busy info in Exchange/Outlook environment

Tags: exchange, outlook, calendar

I have users who are unknowingly scheduling meetings over top of meetings with other users.  When they schedule the meeting, it shows that the other user is free but they are actually already scheduled to attend other meetings.

I checked to make sure the users' Free/Busy settings are correct.  It is set to publish and update every 15 minutes.  Everything looks good.  The only way we've figured out how to fix this issue is to remove the cached version of a person's calendar and re-add it.

Any other ideas as to why this may be happening?

Comment: Just to clarify, the calendars are shared out correctly, and normally users can see busy times - but in occasional instances, appointments are not being updated?

Comment: Yes, calendars are shared out correctly.  When scheduling a meeting with a user within Outlook, they are not seeing their existing meetings when viewing their calendars under the Scheduling tab.

Comment: Which version of Exchange and Outlook? There are **quite** some differences in how free/busy works between 2003 and 2007, both server- and client-side.

Comment: Exchange 2003 and Outlook 2003

Comment: I've also noticed that when scheduling a meeting with this user, when I look at the user's calendar on the Scheduling tab, it only show certain meetings, but when I minimize that window and look at the user's calendar using the Open a Shared Calendar link, I can see all of the appointments.

Why would the Scheduling tab limit the number of meetings visible to a user? I'm guessing this information is cached somehow but how would I repair this file or force an update?

Answer (score 2):

You might try taking two users who have this problem and launching Outlook on their machines with the /cleanfreebusy switch, which will reset the free/busy bitmap for their calendars. You can then try scheduling meetings between the two of them and see whether that fixes the problem.

Comment: I've already tried the following:

- Run the ScanOST.exe utility against the Offline Folder File
- Turn off cached mode, close down Outlook. Delete the OST file then restart Outlook. Enable cached mode again.
- Tried starting Outlook with each of the following switches:
/CleanFreeBusy
/CleanReminders
/ResetFolders
/CleanViews
- Checked to make sure that both associates have new mail delivered to their Exchange mailbox and not a PST file

Comment: I've also noticed that when scheduling a meeting with this user, when I look at the user's calendar on the Scheduling tab, it only show certain meetings, but when I minimize that window and look at the user's calendar using the Open a Shared Calendar link, I can see all of the appointments. Why would the Scheduling tab limit the number of meetings visible to a user? I'm guessing this information is cached somehow but how would I repair this file or force an update?